# Why is my conditional function of adding an item from an array to another one not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Basically I have an array called "Heroes" and through buttons I'm trying to add or delete certain items from that array to another one called "favorites".
When adding a hero to favorites, the message "item added to favorites!" appears, but the part in which I display my favorites in the document appears to show a blank space instead of the hero's name like I want to. Also, the part of showing "item already added" or "favorites list full" doesn't work.
Also, when trying to add more than a hero to favorites, it doesn't allow me to. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The "clear favorites" button works just fine, and the "remove favorite" appears to do so as well.

´´´

```
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

const addToFavorites = (id) => {
  if (favorites.includes((heroin) => heroin.id === id)){
    setMessage("hero already in favorites!")
  } if (favorites.length = 6) {
    setMessage("favorites list full!")
  }
    const newFavorites = favorites.concat(heroin => heroin.id === id)
    setFavorites(newFavorites)
    setMessage("item added to favorites!")
  }

const deleteFavorite = (id) => {
 const newFavorites = favorites.filter((heroin) => heroin.id !== id)
 setFavorites(newFavorites);
 setMessage("");
}

 {heroes.map((heroin)=>{
      const {id, props} = heroin;
      return <div key={id}><h1>{props}</h1></div>;
})

<button onClick={clearFavorites}>Clear favorites</button>
 <button value={id} onClick={()=>addToFavorites(id)}>
            Add to favorites</button>
            <button value={id} onClick={()=> deleteFavorite(id)}>remove favorite</button>
        <h4>{message}</h4>

{favorites.map((favorite)=>{
      const {name} = favorite;
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          </div>
      )
    })}
```

´´´

Comment: `const newFavorites = favorites.concat(heroin => heroin.id === id)` What is this trying to do?

Comment: First of all You should pass `searchElement` to `includes`, You are passing predicate function. Which always returns `false`

Comment: concat function is trying to add to the favorites array the heroin object.

Comment: how do I pass search element?

Comment: `concat function is trying to add to the favorites array the heroin object. ` You're passing a function into .concat, so that function gets added to the array. If you want to add an object, you need to pass an object. Something like `const newFavorites = favorites.concat({ id: id, name: 'example' })`

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

You are calling array functions that don't take callbacks.

- `Array.prorotype.includes` takes a value, not a predicate function. Since the `favorites` array doesn't have an exact strictly equal version of the `(heroin) => heroin.id === id)` function, false is returned because no element can match.
- `Array.prototype.concat` will add whatever the value is that is passed to to a new copy of the array and return the array.
- `favorites.length = 6` is attempting to assign a value to the length property.

Code:

```
const addToFavorites = (id) => {
  if (favorites.includes((heroin) => heroin.id === id)) { // Always false!
    setMessage("hero already in favorites!");
  }
  if (favorites.length = 6) {
    setMessage("favorites list full!");
  }
  const newFavorites = favorites.concat(heroin => heroin.id === id); // only adds function instead of hero object
  setFavorites(newFavorites);
  setMessage("item added to favorites!");
}
```

## Solution

- Use `Array.prototype.find` to search the array for a specific value using a predicate function.
- Concatenate the found element if not already contained in array.

Code:

```
const addToFavorites = (id) => {
  const hero = favorites.find((heroin) => heroin.id === id);

  if (hero) {
    setMessage("hero already in favorites!");
  } else {
    if (favorites.length === 6) {
      setMessage("favorites list full!");
    } else {
      setFavorites(favorites => favorites.concat(hero));
      setMessage("item added to favorites!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate  your effort but the issue wasn't solved. It still says as if the favorite list was full even if it is the first favorite I add. And also it allows me to remove items I didn't even add in the first place.

Comment: `favorites.length = 6` This is *assigning* 6, not comparing it. Change it to `favorites.length === 6`

Comment: now it crashes the web when I click the "add to favorites" button and says TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'favorite' as it is undefined.

Comment: @AmadeodelaPeña Do the hero elements in the `heroes` array have a `name` property to render? If `favorites` is an array and you are iterating it and naming each element `favorite` then it should certainly exist.